# Gradle command line startup error

Tags: windows, command-line, gradle

I started reading the gradle user guide and tried to reproduce what is done there.
So i created a file "build.gradle" and put it in here:
"c:\development\build.gradle".

That file includes the following text:

```
task compile << {
    println 'compiling source'
}

task compileTest(dependsOn: compile) << {
    println 'compiling unit tests'
}

task test(dependsOn: [compile, compileTest]) << {
    println 'running unit tests'
}

task dist(dependsOn: [compile, test]) << {
    println 'building the distribution'
}
```

Now I opened a Windows command windows and typed in this:

```
gradle -b C:\development\build.gradle dist test
```

This is what I got:

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - Where: Build file 'C:\development\build.gradle' line: 1
> - What went wrong: A problem occurred evaluating root project 'development'.
>
>   > Could not find property 'compile' on root project 'development'.
> - Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
>
> BUILD FAILED

After some tries I found, that the file itself was been found, but I don't know why it is not executed.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution by myself.

Make sure, that your build file has the same encoding as your operating system.
In my case I created a UTF-8 file, but should have been an ISO-file.

After changing to the correct encoding, everything works fine.